# Android Multi fragment Management

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view

I have two Fragments in a FragmentTabHost called "List" and "Map"
Map calls a SupportMapFragment.

My app start in List, I switch to Map and switch back to list = everything is great :D
But when I switch back to Map the application crash because I duplicated the map id.

My condition is: If you have creat the view do not do anything.
It doesn't crash but it doesn't display :/

What should I do ?

MapFragment.java

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment{

    private View view;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (view != null){
            return null;
        }
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, null, false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
         class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
         />
```

logcat

```
07-10 16:44:36.966: E/AndroidRuntime(7693): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-10 16:44:36.966: E/AndroidRuntime(7693): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
07-10 16:44:36.966: E/AndroidRuntime(7693):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
07-10 16:44:36.966: E/AndroidRuntime(7693):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
07-10 16:44:36.966: E/AndroidRuntime(7693):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
07-10 16:44:36.966: E/AndroidRuntime(7693):     at com.immo.d3androidv6.Fragment2.onCreateView(Fragment2.java:25)
07-10 16:44:36.966: E/AndroidRuntime(7693):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
07-10 16:44:36.966: E/AndroidRuntime(7693):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
07-10 16:44:36.966: E/AndroidRuntime(7693):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1264)
07-10 16:44:36.966: E/AndroidRuntime(7693):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:672)
07-10 16:44:36.966: E/AndroidRuntime(7693):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
07-10 16:44:36.966: E/AndroidRuntime(7693):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
07-10 16:44:36.966: E/AndroidRuntime(7693):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-10 16:44:36.966: E/AndroidRuntime(7693):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-10 16:44:36.966: E/AndroidRuntime(7693):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-10 16:44:36.966: E/AndroidRuntime(7693):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-10 16:44:36.966: E/AndroidRuntime(7693):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 16:44:36.966: E/AndroidRuntime(7693):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-10 16:44:36.966: E/AndroidRuntime(7693):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-10 16:44:36.966: E/AndroidRuntime(7693):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-10 16:44:36.966: E/AndroidRuntime(7693):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-10 16:44:36.966: E/AndroidRuntime(7693): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #2: Duplicate id 0x7f050007, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
07-10 16:44:36.966: E/AndroidRuntime(7693):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:285)
07-10 16:44:36.966: E/AndroidRuntime(7693):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
07-10 16:44:36.966: E/AndroidRuntime(7693):     ... 18 more
```

Comment: if you have a crash, post a stacktrace from logcat.

Comment: I fixed with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928833/android-app-error-duplicate-id-0x7f04000f-tag-null-or-parent-id-0x0-with-ano/14929151#14929151

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inflating a layout that references a SupportMapFrafment but you are extending Fragment. What you can do is just extend SupportMapFragment and do not override any method or define a static fragment on the Map tab

Comment: I wish I could but I cann't extend SupportMapFragment.
Because my tabhost is waiting an extend Fragment :/

Comment: Ok you were right. I don't know what I did but know I can use SupportMapFragment instead of Fragment. thx!