# app getting crash while resume app

Tags: android, android-fragments, drawerlayout, onresume

Please any one help me, I am new in android studio, my app getting crash while resume application,

I have three different fragment layout which have

```
 <fragment 
    android:id="@+id/map_online"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/action_bar" /> with different ID.
```

while resume application I need to load one Fragment with map,

I am getting following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line
>
> ## 39: Duplicate id 0x7f0f018a, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

Please any one sugggest how to solve this.

This is my fragment class:

```
  public class ClientRequestFragment extends Fragment implements  OnMapReadyCallback {

View clientRequestView;
private static final String TAG = ClientRequestFragment.class.getSimpleName();
GoogleMap googleMap;
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_online);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    clientRequestView = li.inflate(R.layout.offline_fragment, container, false);

    return clientRequestView;
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack,
                        String tag, boolean isAnimate) {
    FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    if (isAnimate) {
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right,
                R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_left,
                R.anim.slide_out_right);
    }

    if (addToBackStack) {
        ft.addToBackStack(tag);
    }
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, tag);
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();


}
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    this.googleMap = googleMap;
    //googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
 /*   try {
        // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
        // in a raw resource file.
        boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(
                MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                        getActivity(), R.raw.retro_style_json));

        if (!success) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");
        }
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can't find style. Error: ", e);
    }*/


} 

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
     FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = (fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map_online));
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.remove(fragment);
    ft.commit();

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();


}

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083950/duplicate-id-tag-null-or-parent-id-with-another-fragment-for-com-google-androi

Comment: Can we see your fragment code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928833/android-app-error-duplicate-id-0x7f04000f-tag-null-or-parent-id-0x0-with-ano

Comment: @MaharithAdityaSS avoid posting that much code in a comment pls

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley Sorry :(

Comment: Btw we need all three fragment's codes. The exception says you are using duplicates ID

Comment: like above one fragment class i have created two another fragment with different MAP id.

Comment: post the 3 xml codes pls

Comment: I have use this  <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_online"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/action_bar" />

Comment: in other fragment layout i used same with different id like client1Map and JobMap

Comment: I faced same issue ar a time I used `MapView` instead of `SupportMapFragment‌​`.  And Problem is resolved.

Comment: i have used MapView in eclipse it working fine but now i am converting it into android studio

Comment: Now Mapview is deprecated in   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.+'

Comment: [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14768343/4700782)

Comment: still getting same error  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #39: Duplicate id 0x7f0f018a, tag null, or parent id 0xffffffff with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

Answer (score 0):

Your app getting crash because static fragment inside fragment can not be remove or replace , you can only hide or show this static fragment.
make your xml file like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/coreLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_home_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

in your fragment.java file write this code:

```
 PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragmentSourceAddress = new PlaceAutocompleteFragment();
  replaceFragment(autocompleteFragmentSourceAddress, R.id.fragment_home_container);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove fragment before push new one in your fragment view have been re-created so add `==null` condition in `onCreatedView` method,

```
View mainView;// this should be global variable.

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(mainview==null){
           mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
           initializeView();//initialize all views in this method instead of onActivityCreated 
        }
        return mainView;
    }
```

> Add this when you push above fragment to avoid duplication

```
try {
     android.app.Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_online);
     if (fragment != null) {
         android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         ft.remove(fragment);
         ft.commit();
     }
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```