# How to use Android Google Map V2 as a fragment in Sliding menu?

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

I am using sliding menu with ActionBarSherlock and need to show android google map v2 in a fragment. The class extends SherlockFragment. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14768343/1276967 It works with SherlockFragment but having inflating problems rarely. Maybe because of other issues..

Answer (score 1):

The best way will be to extend `SupportMapFragment` and do all you logic there.

Then you can simply add this fragment in a `ViewPager` using `FragmentPagerAdapter` with a dataset of:

```
class FrgInfo {
    Class clss;
    Bundle args;
}
```

and overriding the `getItem` method:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(final int position) {
    final FrgInfo info = fragments.get(position);
    return Fragment.instantiate(context, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
}
```

This should do the trick.