# Error inflating Map with fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

I've seen a lot of posts of this error, I've tried almost all of them but it didn't solved my problem... The thing is that I've got a Fragment that I want to put a MapView, then the thing is that when I try to inflate it crashes...

I've added all on Manifest, I've added the library, etc...

MainActivity.java (I tried to put FragmentActivity on my PhotosFragment.java but I've got this case)

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 1:
        fragment = new PhotosFragment();
        break;
```

Well on my PhotosFragment.java I tried this code :

```
public class PhotosFragment extends Fragment {

public PhotosFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photos, container, false); //PhotosFragment.java:20
}
```

}

And my `fragment_photos.xml` is like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

I had `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"` and I read that you have to put `SupportMapFragment`.

LogCat Error

```
01-11 22:41:01.258    3081-3081/info.androidhive.slidingmenu E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: info.androidhive.slidingmenu, PID: 3081
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.PhotosFragment.onCreateView(PhotosFragment.java:20)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4822)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.PhotosFragment.onCreateView(PhotosFragment.java:20)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #2: Duplicate id 0x7f0d001f, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0d0018 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4808)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.PhotosFragment.onCreateView(PhotosFragment.java:20)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4822)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:469)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.PhotosFragment.onCreateView(PhotosFragment.java:20)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

activity_main.xml code

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What does "it crashes" mean?  Is there an error message?  Please don't make everyone guess.

Comment: Whoops, sorry I knew I had forgotten something.

Comment: @DavidWallace Take a look to what I've edited.

Comment: @JoanColmenero could you also post the layout of your activity?

Comment: Do you mean `fragment_photos.xml`?

Comment: No. The layout of `MainActivity`.

Comment: Perhaps you've got two fragments with the same id in your XML?

Comment: What do you mean? I don't think so.. because it doesn't appear any error on my xml

Comment: Well, your error clearly says `"Binary XML file line #2: Duplicate id 0x7f0d001f, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0d0018 with another fragment"`, so somehow you're either loading that fragment twice, or you've duplicated the id.

Comment: How do I know what is the "duplicate id"?

Comment: I'd just search for the id `0x7f0d001f` in the file and see if it shows up twice.

Comment: It was a variable that I was created called "mapa" but I've changed it again... I don't know why this variable is still crashing, I've done a clear project and rebuild project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting all nested fragments in `onDestroyView()` and inflating them in `onCreateView` like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14768343/2185634) suggests.

Comment: I tried this answer... and I can't use the ´getSupportFragmentManager()´ and I tried to remove the ´Support´ and it doesn't give to me any error OF CODE but it still crashing...

Comment: try using `getChildFragmentManager` instead